# Python Random Equations

Tags: python

Write a function called random_equation that takes as input a single parameter, the number of operators to generate in the random equation, and returns a string representing a random math equation involving the numbers 1-10 and operators +, -, *.

```
def random_equation(num): 
    result = ""
    for i in range (num):
        number = random.randint(1, 10)
        if number == 1:
            num_gen = (" 1 ")
        elif number == 2:
            num_gen = (" 2 ")
        elif number == 3:
            num_gen = (" 3 ")
        elif number == 4:
            num_gen = (" 4 ")
        elif number == 5:
            num_gen = (" 5 ")
        elif number == 6:
            num_gen = (" 6 ")
        elif number == 7:
            num_gen = (" 7 ")
        elif number == 8:
            num_gen = (" 8 ")
        elif number == 9:
            num_gen = (" 9 ")
        else:
            num_gen = (" 10 ")


        operator = random.randint(1,4)
        if operator == 1:
            op_gen = (" + ")
        elif operator == 2:
            op_gen = (" - ")
        else:
            op_gen = (" * ")


        math = result + num_gen + op_gen
```

I don't really know where to put the [i] to get it to repeat the loop since number is an integer and num_gen is the result

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [help on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question. In particular, note that we are not your students: you do not get to issue us tasks. We will be more than happy to help you with your homework, but we will not do it for you. Please show what you have done, and which specific problems you have encountered. If you just want code written for you, hire a programmer.

Comment: Thank you. Now we can talk. :)

Comment: right now its just producing a single random integer and operator

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here.

- Your `math` gets replaced every time (e.g. `"" + " 2 " + " - "`), thus you never get to build longer sequences. You want to make `result` longer in each iteration: `result = result + num_gen + op_gen`, instead of always creating a new `math` with an empty `result`.
- You never `return` anything. You will want to `return result` when the loop is finished.
- You are now generating `num` numbers and `num` operators; that will produce equations like `1  +  3  *`, which are a bit unbalanced. You will want to put only `num - 1` pairs, and then one more number.
- There are easier ways to make a string out of a number; `str(num)` will do what you do in twenty lines, just without the spaces.
- With `operator` from 1 to 4, you will be generating as many `*` as you do `+` and `-` combined. Intentional?

Comment: Do I not have to include an [i] somewhere to get the loop to repeat itself?

Comment: No. Loop repeats itself; that is its function. `[i]` accesses `i`-th element on an array (or a string), that is its function. The two have nothing to do with each other (and you have no arrays in your code). Your loop works; but you would only be getting the last `math`, because you kept overwriting it. You could verify that the loop is indeed looping, if you do `print math` immediately after the `math = ...` line (at the same indent level).

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
question = str(random.randint(-10,100)) + random.choice(op) + str(random.randint(-10,100)) + random.choice(op) + str(random.randint(-10,100))
q_formatted = question.replace('÷','/').replace('×',  '*')
answer = eval(q_formatted)
print(answer)
```

Comment: OP is asking a specific question about the code they posted. While a completely different code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't answer the question. Please [edit] this answer to address the problems with OP's original code.